# How to get a javascript overlay to load on startup

Tags: javascript, overlay

I want to have a javascript overlay box load on startup inviting users to participate in a feedback survey.  How can I do this.  I do not want a separate window.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Christopher,

It sounds like you want a non-intrusive "pop-up" dialog, but for it just to overlay the main page and not show up in a separate browser window. "jQuery UI" has lots of built-in goodies like this. A simple example of the code may look like this:

```
<script src="jquery.js" />
<script src="jquery-ui.js" />
<script type="text/javascript">
$(window).load(function () {
  $("#overlay_box").dialog();
});
</script>
...
<div id="overlay_box">
<!-- your HTML content here -->
</div>
```

For a live demo of the code above, as well as more details, visit:
http://jqueryui.com/demos/dialog/

Hope that helps.

-tjw

Answer (score 1):

You would want to use a div that you can show when the form is finished loading or some other event occurs. Here are a couple examples [sample1](http://raven-seo-tools.com/blog/2911/create-a-modal-dialog-using-css-and-javascript), [sample2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/873184/javascript-image-overlay-over-a-specified-div)

Answer (score 0):

You could add function to window.onload thats shows you overlay when the page is loaded
also are you using any framework alot of them have functionality like that.